# How to Perform Mathematical Operation on One Value of a CSV file?

Tags: python, csv, math

I am dealing with a csv file that contains three columns and three rows containing numeric data.  The csv data file simply looks like the following:

```
 Colum1,Colum2,Colum3
 1,2,3
 1,2,3
 1,2,3
```

My question is how to write a python code that take a single value of one of the column and perform a specific operation.  For example, let say I want to take the first value in 'Colum1' and subtract it from the sum of all the values in the column.

Here is my attempt:

```
import csv
f = open('columns.csv')
rows = csv.DictReader(f)

value_of_single_row = 0.0
for i in rows:
    value_of_single_Row += float(i) # trying to isolate a single value here!
print value_of_single_row - sum(float(r['Colum1']) for r in rows) 
f.close()
```

Comment: Have you attempted the code at this? Can you provide it please?

Comment: @idjaw I just have added my attempt at the top.

Comment: To start you off, you have a syntax error. You wrote 'Colum1' instead of 'Column1'

Comment: @idjaw That is still consistent with the code.  I should not have synthax error because the header `Colum1, Colum2, Colum3` are called the exact the same in the code `Colum1`.  I hope you can see that

Comment: Ah yes, understood. I was running it on my end and wrote it as Column. I noticed how you wrote it.

Comment: So the next question then. Is what is the unexpected behaviour you are experiencing. Are you receiving any errors on your end that you can be explicit about?

Comment: @idjaw I am get zeros as a result! Not sure why

Comment: Of course you get zeros as a result. valueOf_single_Row is not value_of_single_row.

Comment: @RégisB. I have modified it but still giving me zeros!

Comment: @MEhsan look at my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the code you provided, I suggest you take a look at the doc to see the preferred approach on how to read through a csv file. Take a look here:

[How to use CsvReader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)

with that being said, you can modify the beginning of your code slightly to this:

```
import csv

with open('data.csv', 'rb') as f:
    rows = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in rows:
        # perform operation per row
```

From there you now have access to each row.

This should give you what you need to do proper row-by-row operations.

What I suggest you do is play around with printing out your rows to see what your data looks like. You will see that each row being outputted is a dictionary.

So if you were going through each row, you can just simply do something like this:

```
for row in rows:
  row['Colum1'] # or row.get('Colum1')
  # to do some math to add everything in Column1
  s += float(row['Column1'])
```

So all of that will look like this:

```
import csv

s = 0
with open('data.csv', 'rb') as f:
    rows = csv.DictReader(f)

    for row in rows:
        s += float(row['Colum1'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do pretty much all of this with pandas

```
from pandas import DataFrame, read_csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import sys
import os


Location = r'path/test.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(Location, names=['Colum1','Colum2','Colum3'])
df = df[1:] #Remove the headers since they're unnecessary
print df

df.xs(1)['Colum1']=int(df.loc[1,'Colum1'])+5
print df
```

You can write back to your csv using `df.to_csv('File path', index=False,header=True)` Having `headers=True` will add the headers back in.
To do this more along the lines of what you have you can do it like this

```
import csv

Location = r'C:/Users/tnabrelsfo/Documents/Programs/Stack/test.csv'
data = []
with open(Location, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        data.append(line.replace('\n','').replace(' ','').split(','))
    data = data[1:]
    print data
    data[1][1] = 5
    print data
```

it will read in each row, cut out the column names, and then you can modify the values by index

Comment: I am beginner to python and I want to build on my knowledge so far... Would you mind giving me an idea how to get my attempt working instead of coding from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

So here is my simple solution using `pandas` library. Suppose we have `sample.csv` file

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv') # df is now a DataFrame
df['Colum1'] = df['Colum1'] - df['Colum1'].sum() # here we replace the column by subtracting sum of value in the column
print df
df.to_csv('sample.csv', index=False) # save dataframe back to csv file
```

You can also use `map` function to do operation to one column, for example,

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
col_sum = df['Colum1'].sum() # sum of the first column
df['Colum1'] = df['Colum1'].map(lambda x: x - col_sum)
```